# Command to delete build folders under all directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, terminal

Let's say I have folders named "build" under each of 10 directories.

```
C:\A\build
C:\B\build
...upto
C:\J\build
```

I am under `C:\` currently. What's a single command to delete all the build folders from under each of the A to J directories.

Tried with wildcards:

```
rmdir /s /q "*\build\"
```

Not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop would suffice:

```
for %%L in (A B C D E F G H I J) do rmdir /s /q "%%L\build"
```

If you know there are no folders with `build` subfolders that should be retained, you can also just loop over all directories:

```
for /d %%D in (*) do rmdir /s /q "%%D\build"
```

Comment: What if I have 100 folders? I would have to write down all the names in that loop and save them as a bat file for future use?
No better way?

Comment: Sure there are other ways that are more general. But that wasn't your question. Usually I'd just use `for /d %%D in (*) do rmdir /s /q "%%D\build"`, but you're doing things in the root directory of `C:\` (where normal users shouldn't even have write access), so I'd classify such an approach as a little bit dangerous there, since you have a fair chance of clobbering the OS or other important files as well.

Comment: It's not actually root of C: That was just an example.
Anyways, thanks a lot :)